# Route53 WWW Subdomain Not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I've looked around trying to fix my website App Opps [(appopps.com)](http://appopps.com) to have a www subdomain. I've looked around on Stackoverflow but could not find anything to help me. I tried setting up a redirecting Alias Record Set pointing from www.appopps.com to appopps.com but that hasn't worked.

Error Message:
[image]

Record Set setup
[image]

Redirect setup
[image]

I'm sure I'm missing something super simple here and sorry for the basic question in advance!

EDIT

[image]

Comment: It's way easier to temporarily hide that chrome bar with CMD + Shift + B than to censor your bookmarks. Also, all the other 'censored' info on the domain is publicly available

Comment: @booky99 Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The www should use the same alias as the primary .com record (presumably your load balancer)

Comment: I tried creating an Alias with the same cloudfront url (see edit) but didn't work. I'm not sure what you mean the ".com" record. The name server record?

Comment: I also went through and made each record in the listing with "www.". Any combination I tried either didn't do anything or broke the base domain mapping to appopps.com

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's no such thing as a redirecting alias record.

With DNS records you can only achieve a behaviour that both www and apex domain will point to the same location. Any redirection from www to non-www (or vice-versa) is going to happen on a server of some kind. You don't have to provision that server though.

You could for example [set a redirect on an S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/redirect-website-requests.html) (and also distribute it as a CloudFront distribution) to redirect to the desirable domain. Then you'd use the url of the bucket (or distribution) as the target for your Route53 record.

As always with DNS, you have to keep in mind that any changes made to your configuration may take some time to propagate (several hours).